# Lazy Loading Custom module in Spartacus 3.3.0 not working

Tags: spartacus-storefront

trying to lazy load one of my custom feature module. it creates chunk but not lazily working in browser. it loads at first time . please suggest what I am missing here...

[image]

Comment: Hi guys, any update?

Comment: Why is your path underlined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact the chunk is created it looks like you are missing the `cmsComponents` array.

You need to list the CMS components present in your lazy loaded module, that way Spartacus will know when to load the chunk. Please see https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information and also a quick example I sprung up https://github.com/LTiger14/custom-style-spartacus/blob/main/src/app/app.module.ts#L26-L33.